# SQL Server - Calculate elapsed time between multiple columns containing datetime stamps in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a table that contains two columns.  One column that has an action code and the second column that has a DateTime stamp

I am somewhat familiar with comparing DateTime from two different columns on the same row, but not from one column from multiple rows

Sample data:

```
Task_ID     Action_Code CreateDate
----------- ----------- -----------------------
474344      BEGIN       2018-09-28 15:00:00
474344      PAUSE       2018-09-28 16:07:29
474344      RESUME      2018-09-28 16:08:49
474344      PAUSE       2018-09-28 16:09:57
474344      RESUME      2018-09-28 16:11:20
474344      CLOSE       2018-09-28 17:00:00

474390      BEGIN       2018-09-28 11:00:00
474390      PAUSE       2018-09-28 11:07:29
474390      RESUME      2018-09-28 11:08:49
474390      PAUSE       2018-09-28 11:09:57
474390      CLOSE       2018-09-28 12:00:00
```

For Task_ID 474344, I would expect the total time calculated to be 1:57:17 (1 hour, 57 minutes, 17 seconds).

For Task_ID 474390, I would expect the total time calculated to be 0:8:37 (8 minutes, 37 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found my answer:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, pCreateDate, CreateDate)
  FROM (
        SELECT *, LAG(CreateDate) OVER (ORDER BY CreateDate) pCreateDate
        FROM TaskDataBase
          WHERE (Action_Code = 'Pause' OR Action_Code = 'Resume') AND Task_ID = '474344') q
  WHERE pCreateDate IS NOT NULL AND Action_Code = 'Resume';
```

The above will give me

```
(No column name)
----------------
80
83
```

I could then add those two to get 163 seconds, and remove it from the time comparison of the BEGIN and CLOSE times (which is 2 hours, or 7,200 seconds), which would give me a total time of 1 hour, 57 minutes, 17 seconds